# How do I incorperate a line break in a web app? (HTML,CSS)

Tags: html, css, web, web-applications, authentication

So I have been researching this for the past 10 or so minutes and am now bringing it to this community. I don't know how to make a break like this:
[image: A line break with "or" in the center.]

I know there used to be an "hr" tag like so,

---

but its depreciated and I'd prefer to use something else. Its a common thing for login pages where its Email login "or" login with a social account. If you have any tips or find anything, please link it down below!

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: Who said it’s deprecated?

Comment: To clarify, like the quote in @Ivan86's answer mentions, all the layout attributes in <hr> are deprecated. Maybe you misinterpreted that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I personally would use an HR with confidence, but if I didn't want to use HRs I'd try something like this, using the [:after selector](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_after.asp).

```css
p {
  text-align: center;
  }
p span {
  background-color: #fff;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 0 3px;
}
p:after {
    content: '';
    display: block;
    border-bottom: 1px solid black;
    margin-top: -8px;
}
```

```html
<p><span>or</span></p>
```

Answer (score 2):

The `<hr>` is not deprecated.

> In HTML5, the `<hr>` tag defines a thematic break.
>
> In HTML 4.01, the `<hr>` tag represents a horizontal rule.
>
> However, the `<hr>` tag may still be displayed as a horizontal rule in visual browsers, but is now defined in semantic terms, rather than presentational terms.
>
> All the layout attributes are removed in HTML5. Use CSS instead.

For more check [https://www.w3schools.com/tag_hr](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_hr.asp).

An alternative would be to use for example `<div>s` and `borders` (check the snippet):

```css
.thisIsFormContainer
{
  position:relative;
  float:left;
  border:1px solid #000;
  border-radius:4px;
  text-align:center;
  padding:20px;
}

.top
{
  position:relative;
  width:90%;
  margin:0px auto 10px auto;
  padding:0;
  border-bottom:1px solid #09f;
}

.fieldGroup
{
  position:relative;
  width:90%;
  margin:0px auto 0px auto;
  padding:0;
  text-align:left;
}

.item
{
  position:relative;
}
```

```html
<div class="thisIsFormContainer">
  <div class="top">
    <div class="item">Send us an email!</div>
  </div>
  <div class="fieldGroup">
    <div class="item">Address:</div>
    <div class="item">Country:</div>
  </div>
  <div class="fieldGroup">
    <div class="item">State:</div>
    <div class="item">City:</div>
  </div>
</div>
```